# How to get updated user data from second time when when open my android app second time after sign up with Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I tried to get updated data from Graph API using accessToken but it always showing Logout button screen.

```
accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
                accessToken = newAccessToken;
            }
        };

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(isFromFb){
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    }
}
if(accessToken != null) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("TestLog user : " , object.toString());
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,picture.type(large),friends");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

[image]

How to get latest profile data second time on wards in Facebook SDK 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I did a small mistake there final I got the answer. I need to get current accessToken first. But earlier I taken only when onCurrentAccessTokenChanged method.

```
accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
            accessToken = newAccessToken;
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(isFromFb){
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    }
}

if(accessToken != null) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("TestLog user : " , object.toString());
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,picture.type(large),friends");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this You have programmatically log out the user after taking user details everytime like  `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`

For more refer here:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-using-facebook-login-application-using-latest-facebook-sdk/

Comment: After logout is it ask authentication again for second time?

Comment: @NaveenKumarM Yes everytime

Comment: But I don't want authenticate every time. Because user already registered with Facebook. So is there any chance to get updated data with out logout?

Comment: Store the user credentials in shared prefrences and based on perform needed operations